# Equation of motion for a coil around a mass, attached with a spring driven by magnetic field?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, differential-equations, models

First of all, thanks for reading and hello! First time poster on Physics Stack Exchange. I'm an electronics engineer (so forgive my poor maths below!) and tend to hang out there.

I have a questions that's been killing me for a few days.

[image]

I need to design some electronics to control a system which I think looks like the above. It is a linear motor connected to a spring. The motor is of type "moving coil", that is, the mass has a coil wrapped around it, within a permeant magnetic field. Some electronics (that I will design) will drive AC current through the coil to make it oscillate at it's resonant frequency.

I understand how to model the electronic side (a coil in an inductor, with a series resistance and a back EMF). Now, the mass spring is not too hard, there's lots of literature. But, this (I believe) is different - it has an additional 'friction' which is the back EMF generated from Len's law (negative of rate of change of flux).

So, I tried to model this system (a coil driving a mass spring system). For me, my end goal is a transfer function, in the laplace domain, that is the input (IE, current through the coil, or the voltage across it). As a side note, this is the reason for the modelling, I'd like to see the implications, if any, about controlling this via a sinusoidal voltage (much easier in electronics to deal with) or a sinusoidal current; this can still be done but the electronics is a little more involved.

## Equations of motion

So, I think I start of with the Newton's second law (assuming there's no resistance in the system, other than the back EMF):

$ \sum F_x = m \cdot a_x $

$ \sum F_x = F_{spring} + F_{BEMF} - F_{Motor} $

$ \sum F_x = -k \cdot x(t) + \frac{\delta \phi}{\delta t} - B \cdot i_{coil}(t) \cdot L $

I think the back emf term can be rewritten using the systems coord frame (x pointing right and y point up):

$ \frac{\delta \phi}{\delta t} = \frac{\delta B \cdot A}{\delta t} = B \cdot \frac{\delta ( x \cdot y)}{\delta t}$

Since the magnetic flux is constant, and so is the area of flux enclosed by the coil in the y coordinate, I took these out of the differential. That leaves us with the x coordinate. Lets put a constraint on the system whereby the coil/mass will never be displaced by more than it's full length, $l_x$. I think that means the area the coil encloses is:

$ A = (l_{x} - x(t)) \cdot y $

$ A = y \cdot l_x - x(t) \cdot y $

Putting this back into the equation yields:

$B \cdot \frac{\delta ( y \cdot l_x - x(t) \cdot y)}{\delta t}$

$y \cdot l_x $ is constant, and so drops out of the differential, and we're left with (I think):

$B \cdot \frac{\delta (- x(t) \cdot y)}{\delta t}$

And, I guess, though I am not too sure, the y term should drop out for the same reason, but it doesn't make intuitive sense to me, but since I applied the rule before I should do the same now:

$A = -B \cdot \frac{\delta x(t)}{\delta t}$

I put this into Newton's second law:

$ \sum F_x = -k \cdot x(t) -B \cdot \frac{\delta x(t)}{\delta t} - B \cdot i_{coil}(t) \cdot L = m \cdot \frac{\delta^2 x(t)}{\delta t^2} $

Rearranging (and using the dot notion) gives:

$\ddot x + \frac{B}{m}\dot x + \frac{k}{m} \cdot x(t)= - \frac{B \cdot L \cdot i_{coil}}{m}$

I then tried taking the Laplace transform of this, with initial conditions at 0:

$ s^2 \cdot X(s) + s \cdot \frac{B}{m} \cdot X(s) + \frac{k}{m} \cdot X(s) = \frac{B \cdot L \cdot I(S)}{s \cdot m}$

Then I make this the transfer function (position to input current):

$ X(S) \cdot (s^2 + s \frac{B}{m} + \frac{k}{m}) = \frac{B \cdot L \cdot I(S)}{s \cdot m}$

$ \frac{X(S)}{I(S)} =  \frac{B \cdot L}{s \cdot m \cdot ((s^2 + s \frac{B}{m} + \frac{k}{m}))} $

Finally, we can expand the brackets and get this:

$ \frac{X(S)}{I(S)} =  \frac{B \cdot L}{s^3 \cdot m + s^2 \cdot B + s \cdot k} $

Does this look correct? Someone did the same analysis, but didn't show me the steps (just assumed the spring mass was a second order resonant system, which I would agree with if it wasn't for the coil) and used motor torque constants as a way of bridging the mechanical / electrical bridge, which I don't think works with a linear motor - but I could be wrong. Either way, they get a second order system and a different answer - But I don't see where I fail in my reasoning? (though, I'm sure I've made some math errors!)

Thanks so much, and sorry for the long post!